# JPanel Layout not rendering as expected

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

My code follows. I want 2 labels in a grid with the labels on top of each other and 2 dropdowns that have the same thing. I want two sets of these.
What I get is just the two labels NEXT to each other and 2 dropdowns NEXT to each other and the first two labels and dropdowns dont appear at all the Dropdowns are the ones that are capitalized. No errors.

```
JPanel grid1 = new JPanel();
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));            
            grid1.add(label1);
            grid1.add(label2);
            add(grid1);
        JPanel grid3 = new JPanel();
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));            
            grid3.add(IHA);
            grid3.add(IVA);
            add(grid3);
        JPanel controlholder1 = new JPanel();
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            controlholder1.add(grid1);
            controlholder1.add(grid3);
            add(controlholder1);


        JPanel grid2 = new JPanel();
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));            
            grid2.add(label3);
            grid2.add(label4);
            add(grid2);
        JPanel grid4 = new JPanel();
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));            
            grid4.add(THA);
            grid4.add(TVA);
            add(grid4);     
        JPanel controlholder2 = new JPanel();       
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            controlholder2.add(grid2);     
            controlholder2.add(grid4);
            add(controlholder2);
```

Thanks[image: The Output]

EDIT: I have 2 labels in a grid layout and I have 2 Dropdowns in another grid . I want both of these in a border layout and I need 2 of these border layouts in another border layout. There are nested things that I dont have a handle on.

Comment: My first thought is you're adding to panels to the center position of a `BorderLayout`, which means only the second panel will be visible

Answer (score 1):

Add one label and one list in BorderLayout.NORTH and the other two in BorderLayout.SOUTH using BorderLayout

Comment: Or use a `GridLayout` with two rows and one column or a `GridBagLayout`

Comment: yeah anyone of them could be used.

Comment: Why are "Help" and "Me" not on top of each other , its a simple grid layout, 2 rows, 1 column ? and what happened to my other 2 labels and listboxes? They are grid layouts, right

Comment: BorderLayout is much more simpler i think you should give it a try.

Comment: @mike628 See my general comment.  You've added two components to the center position of the board layout, meaning that only one is visible

Answer (score 1):

I would do this ;

```
public JPanel getSubPanels(stuff_to_add_to_dropdowns, stuff_to_add_to_labels){
    JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
    subPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    subPanel.add(new JLabel(stuff_to_add_to_labels.get(0));
    subPanel.add(new JComboBox(stuff_to_add_to_dropdowns.get(0);
    subPanel.add(new JLabel(stuff_to_add_to_labels.get(1));
    subPanel.add(new JComboBox(stuff_to_add_to_dropdowns.get(1);
    return subPanel;
}
```

and call it twice adding it to BorderLayout.NORTH and BorderLayout.SOUTH to the parent JPanel

Comment: You forgot the return statement...and what's `stuff_to_add_to_dropdowns` and `stuff_to_add_to_labels`??

Comment: edited in. The parameters are probably going to be lists. Trying to illustrate that verbose GUI code can be reduced.